# All associated primes appear in a series of submodules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

This is essentially Ex VI.4.8 of [Algebra: Chapter 0](http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~jarekw/pdf/Algebra0TextboookAluffi.pdf).

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $M$ be an $R$-module. Define \begin{equation}
\operatorname{Ann}_{R}(m)=\{r\in R:rm=0\}
\end{equation} for each $m\in M$. Each is an ideal of $R$ and call a prime ideal of this form an associate prime.

I can show that if $R$ is Noetherian, then it always has associate primes. If, further, $M$ is finitely generated, then there is a series of submodules of $M$ \begin{equation}
M=:M_0\ge M_1\ge\cdots\ge M_{l}=\{0\}
\end{equation} 
with
$M_{i}/M_{i+1}\cong_{\operatorname{R-Mod}} R/\mathfrak{p_i}
$ with $\mathfrak{p_i}$ being associate primes.

But then I am asked to show that all associate primes are produced by such a complex. That is, if $\mathfrak{p}$ is an associate prime of $R$, then $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{p_i}$ for some $\mathfrak{p_i}$ produced in the complex above.

This seems quite striking since we have quite a lot choice constructing the complex. And I do not know where to start.

Can someone give a hint?

Also, I find it quite hard to think about problems like this. I can only think very abstractly. Is there some mental picture we should have when dealing with such kind of things?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to show two identities:

$$ \rm{Ass}(M) \subset \rm{Ass}(N) \cup \rm{Ass}(M/N)$$

and for any $\mathfrak p \in \rm{Spec}(\rm R)$, $$ \rm{Ass}(R/\mathfrak p) = \{\mathfrak p\}.$$

Comment: $\rm{AP}$ means associated primes.

Comment: The traditional notation is $\operatorname{ass}$. It makes for interesting statements!